# Cannot connect to IBM WS local queue manager when logged as domain user

Tags: ibm-mq

I am logged as a domain user on my machine with Windows 7 (with local admin rights). I have installed IBM WebSphere MQ 7.0 and created queue manager via IBM WS MQ Explorer. I see that queue manager is working but I cannot connect to it. When I login as a local user and run MQ Explorer then I can connect to newly created queue manager and manage its settings.
I guess this is related to some security issues.

I tried to add domain user to "mqm" group but that did not help.
I also tried to set variable: "SET MQSNOAUTH=YES" and then created queue manager - but it also did not work for me.

Any idea on how to solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you configured MQ to run under a domain id when you install (or rerun the prepare wizard). The problem is, if you dont, then when a domain id comes along and MQ is running under a local id (MUSR_MQADMIN), it goes off to the domain controller to find out what groups it is a member of, to be told you are not authorized to know. See the docs here:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ins.doc/q008820_.htm?lang=en

Note there is a subtle difference as to what the prepare wizard does on 7.0 (which sets the id as an identity to a dcom object) vs 7.1+ (which sets the id for the service to run under), but you should always do it through the prepare wizard

Comment: I went through the prepare wizard passing my domain account settings and after completing wizard and restarting MQ Explorer I can connect to local queue manager. It seems that everything is working now. Thank you.